# How to send information from the vue.js file to the controller like an id? Laravel - Inertia-vue

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I'm trying to open a page from a button, but I need to send the id of the item where the button is in. For context this is a discussion forum page, in the users dash they are shown the forums they can comment on and there is a button on the bottom of each, what I need to send is that forums id, so that when they click on the button it takes them to the correct forum view.

How can I do this?

I'm trying different ways

```
<el-button type="primary" @click="submit(f.id)">
    Answer
</el-button>

submit($id) {
    var link = 'comments/' + $id;

    this.$inertia.visit('comments/' + $id, {
        $id,
    });
},
```

```
<inertia-link class="el-button el-button--warning"
    :href="'comments/' + f.id">
        Answer
</inertia-link>
```

In my routes web.php

```
Route::resource('comments', 'ReplyController');
Route::get('comments/{id}', 'ReplyController@index');
```

The index in the controller

```
public function index($id)
{
    $forum = DiscussionForum::where('id', $id)
        ->with('comment', 'user')->first();
    $comment = Reply::with('discussionForum', 'user')
        ->where('discussion_forum_id', $forum->id)
        ->orderByDesc('updated_at')->get();

    return Inertia::render('Forum/Comment.vue', [
        'forum' => $forum,
        'comments' => $comment
    ]);
}
```

This is not working, the redirect shows me a blank window inside the main page? How can I send the forum id correctly?

Comment: What does the `f` variable output? Have a look in your developer tools in the networking tab to see if you get any 500 errors, or the like. Is `APP_DEBUG` set to `true`?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to add a name to the route so:

```
Route::get('comments/{id}')->name('comments')->uses('ReplyController@index');
```

Then you can pass your `id` in the inertia-link in this way:

```
<inertia-link class="el-button el-button--warning"
    :href="route('comments', { f.id })">
        Answer
</inertia-link>
```

This way can be used with Ziggy as mentioned in the docs.
https://inertiajs.com/routing

Comment: This answer only works if you're using Ziggy by TightenCo(or if you have sort of other route method wired up somewhere).

Comment: Ziggy is suggested to use when working with Inerita. It's said also in the offical documentation

Comment: Sure, I didn't dispute that. You just didn't mention that it would be needed for your answer to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the emit function here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Something like this:

```
yourMethod() {
  this.$emit(
    "someName",
    this.id
  );
}
```

Comment: what about the redirect?

Comment: @Nancy `location.reload();`