# Get data from URL using Inertia

Tags: reactjs, inertiajs

I am using [InertiaJs](https://inertiajs.com/links) library to create links as in the following:

```js
<InertiaLink href={`/item/`+ itemId}>Go to the page</InertiaLink>
```

Clicking on this, the link will look like this: `/item/156654`

Question: How to get the `itemId`(156654,54654654, ... ) from the link above using Inertia?

I know that in React there is a function `let history = useHistory();`, but this approach doesn't work for me. What alternative exists?

Comment: Just to clarify: when you say "Get The ItemId From the link", do you mean within this scope, or on another page?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58840998/how-to-send-information-from-the-vue-js-file-to-the-controller-like-an-id-larav This seems to have the answer you need

Comment: @AaronMorefield, i want to get the id in another age, in the page where user will be redirected when will click on `<InertiaLink href={`/item/`+ itemId}>Go to the page</InertiaLink>`

Comment: If that is the case, can you post some of the code for where you would want to receive the code so that we can assist?

Comment: @AaronMorefield, the idea is simple. I have the Component `A` whare i have this code: `<InertiaLink href={`/item/`+ itemId}>Go to the page</InertiaLink>`, clicking on the link i will be redirected to the component `B`. So, i want to know how to get the Id from URL in the component B. Please, tell me if you got me. Do you know  a solution?

Comment: My guess is that you'd have to do some manual URL parsing, which seems simple enough to do :)

Comment: @Asking Did you tried setting ItemId in local storage before calling InertiaLink in component A and then retrieving it in component B? I think that will be the easiest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<InertiaLink />` don't provide any context to opened page, so you need to parse URL manually. In the example below you can find `parsePageId()` function which actually parse location path in [an optimal way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url-in-jquery).

```js
// solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url-in-jquery
const parsePageId = (path) => path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)

const Page = () => {
  const pageId = parsePageId(window.location.pathname)
  
  // will render "Page id: js", because snippet href is "https://stacksnippets.net/js"
  return (
    <p>Page id: <b>{pageId}</b></p>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(<Page />, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `window.location` object to get the actual URL and then apply a simple parsing to obtain the item id:

```
const { pathname } = window.location
const splitPathname = pathname.split("/")
const itemId = splitPathname[splitPathname.length - 1]
```

We are just getting all the parts of the URL separated by "/" and getting the last one, which will be the item id.